# Graph_tool 's find_vertex() raises a Exception

Tags: python

I generate a graph with the word of a sentence as tokens and dependency relations as edges.

This info comes from a external Tool in the format of ((word, index), (word, index),  relation) tuple. Each word can have many dependencies and I want only one node per word.

When I process each dependency I want to search it by their ID, but when i Try to use find_vertex() i get the next Exception:

```
TypeError: No registered converter was able to extract a C++ reference to type graph_tool::GraphInterface from this Python object of type Graph
```

This is the code:

```
def graph(self, sentence, sentenceNamespace="sentence", separator="_"):
    graph = Graph()
    root_node = graph.add_vertex()
    # Create a link to Root Node
    graph.graph_properties['root'] = graph.new_graph_property("python::object", root_node)
    # Create Node's properties
    graph.vertex_properties['id'] = graph.new_vertex_property("string")
    graph.vertex_properties['form'] = graph.new_vertex_property("string")
    graph.vertex_properties['ord'] = graph.new_vertex_property("int64_t")
    # Create edge's properties
    graph.edge_properties['type'] = graph.new_edge_property("string")
    # Create the root node
    graph.vertex_properties['form'][root_node] = "S"
    graph.vertex_properties['ord'][root_node] = -1
    # Find or create the dependant and governor nodes and link with a new edge
    for dependency in self.dependency(sentence):
        dependency_governor = dependency[0]
        # Governor's generated ID
        governor_name = "{1}{0}{2[0]}{0}{1[1]}".format(separator, sentenceNamespace,dependency_governor )
        dependency_dependant = dependency[1]
        # Dependant's generated ID
        dependant_name = "{1}{0}{2[0]}{0}{1[1]}".format(separator, sentenceNamespace, dependency_dependant)
        # Relation Type
        relation = dependency[2]

# This is the problematic Line ################################################

        governor = find_vertex(graph, graph.vertex_properties['id'], governor_name)

##############################################################
        # If search is successful use the first node else create a new one
        if governor :
            governor = governor[0]
        else:
            governor = graph.add_vertex()
            graph.vertex_properties['id'][governor] = governor_name
            graph.vertex_properties['form'][governor] = dependency_governor[0]
            graph.vertex_properties['ord'][governor] = dependency_governor[1]

        dependant = find_vertex(graph, 'id', dependant_name)
        # If search is successful use the first node else create a new one
        if dependant :
            dependant = dependant[0]
        else:
            dependant = graph.add_vertex()
            graph.vertex_properties['id'][dependant] = dependant_name
            graph.vertex_properties['form'][dependant] = dependant_dependant[0]
            graph.vertex_properties['ord'][dependant] = dependency_dependant[1]
        # Link the nodes with the new dependency relation
        dependency_edge = graph.add_edge(governor, dependant)
        graph.edge_properties['type'][dependency_edge]= relation
    return graph
```

Comment: Have you considered using a native Python network library -- such as networkx or graphine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the git version.